# VBA Cells.Replace changes the entire spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

**SETUP:**

Using ACCESS 2010 VBA to create sheets in Excel. Below issue is already working on an exported excel file;

**QUESTION:**

I'm having the below code (also tried varieties of it), but sadly it's changing every "-" for "_" in the entire spreadsheet instead only in the cells mentioned. I have no clue why is it happening.

```
For i = 2 To k
If Cells(i, 15).Value Like "*" & "-" & "*" & ":" & "*" Then
Cells(i, 15).Replace What:="-", Replacement:="_" - changes all
Cells(i, 15).Replace What:=":", Replacement:="." - changes all
End If
Next i
```

Highly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code looks correct. I tested on small test data and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that's not working (I can't replicate it). Can you see if this works?

```
For i = 2 To k
    If Cells(i, 15).Value Like "*" & "-" & "*" & ":" & "*" Then
        Cells(i, 15) = Replace(Cells(i, 15), "-", "_")
        Cells(i, 15) = Replace(Cells(i, 15), ":", ".")
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: *`"*" & "-" & "*" & ":" & "*"`* Isn't it the same as `*-*:*`?

Comment: @JohnyL - it is indeed. I might delete the answer actually as there's nothing obviously wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: For some reason replacing 
`Cells(i, 15).Replace What:="-", Replacement:="_"`
with
`Cells(i, 15) = Replace(Cells(i, 15), "-", "_")`
solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is it downvoted? The code syntax is correct and OP has confirmed it works for him. Upvoting...

Comment: It's likely downvoted because it doesn't explain what's going on and the OP doesn't understand what it does or why it works... unlike the much better non-accepted answer below

Answer (score 1):

Op’s code seems like a mix of the `Replace` function and the `Range.Replace`. method.

> **[Replace Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function)**
>
> **Returns:** a string in which a specified substring has been replaced with another substring a specified number of times.
>
> **Syntax:** Replace( expression, find, replace, [start], [count] ,[compare] )

.

> **[Range.Replace Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/range-replace-method-excel)**
>
> **Returns:** a Boolean indicating characters in cells within the specified range. Using this method doesn't change either the selection or the active cell.
>
> **Syntax:** Range.Replace( What, Replacement, [LookAt], [SearchOrder], [MatchCase], [MatchByte], [SearchFormat], [ReplaceFormat] )

While the `Replace` function would need to be applied `Cell` by `Cell`, the `Range.Replace` method can be applied to an entire range. However when the `Range.Replace` method is applied to a single cell the replacements are performed over the entire worksheet.

... and that's what these lines are doing:

```
Cells(i, 15).Replace What:="-", Replacement:="_"
Cells(i, 15).Replace What:=":", Replacement:="."
```

The Range.Replace method does not need to be applied cell by cell neither to validate first if the string to be replaced is present (i.e. `What`), instead apply it directly to the entire range. Try this code:

```
With Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(k, 15))  'change as required
    .Replace What:="-", Replacement:="_", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    .Replace What:=":", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart
End With
```